# Spring Boot - Find A Parent Class by a List of related Children

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the following Parent Class :

```
@Entity
@Data
public class ParentEntity{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(
            name = "parent_child_link",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "child_id"))
    List<ChildEntity> children;
}
```

I also have this child class :

```
@Entity
@Data
public class ChildEntity{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "child_name_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    ChildNameEntity childName;


    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "child_height_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    ChildHeightEntity childHeight;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, mappedBy = "children")
    List<Parent> parents;
}
```

The reason the child has separate objects for name and height is for an experiment on databases, and not storing duplicate values. Obviously this example is a little anonymized.

I'm trying to find a parent (or maybe even multiple parent classes), using JPA... but by the list of children (let's imagine we cannot search by the parent class or ID directly at this point)

I have the following repository line already :

```
List<Parent> findByChildrenIn(List<ChildEntity> children);
```

The Problem I am facing is that I seem to be able to get back every parent which has any of the children.

**I am looking to return back only parents which are a match for containing EVERY child in the list.**